# validatejs confirm password for react-native

Tags: javascript, validation, react-native

I have the following with all of my validations:

```
const validations = {
   password: {
      presence: true
   },

   confirmPassword:{
     equality: {
       attribute: "password",
       message: "Passwords do not match",
       comparator: function(v1, v2) {
        return v1 === v2
       }
     }
   }
}
```

And I want to display the errors separately so I have the following:

```
let passwordError = validate('password', this.state.password);
let confirmPasswordError = validate("confirmPassword", { confirmPassword: this.state.confirmPassword, password: this.state.password});
```

The password validation works well. And the presence validation for the confirmPassowrd works but the equality check doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

already check with a console.log that values were coming to variables v1 and v2? for example to me the variable v1 was coming:

`{confirmPassword:"12345", password:"12345"}`

then just do:

`v1.confirmPassword === v1.password`